# Avg time for human to reach a destination

Tags: probability

A man near a junction has to reach a house of his relative which is 100m away northwards from the junction.He does not know the location of house.So he travels randomly every minute at 100 m/min speed in some random direction(i.e, north,south,East or west)with equal probability.What is the average time of this travel?
My workout is that he can reach the destination in only odd minutes.But the real difficulty is regarding finding probability,as after every minute the probability is getting split into many like branches of a tree. Can someone please help me out how to approach it in a easy way. Thanks in advance
Edit:The path is like a cordinate system, for example he can be at (1,1) or (-1,1) or (2,0),so on .
In the first minute the probability that he reach is 1/4.
Next minute he can't,the third minute he can reach with certain probabilty and so on.There is a pattern in it for sure but I could not get it.I also tried using permutations,that is lets say that he has reached the destination on 17th minute.
It means he has to travel eight pairs of north-south or east-west or combination with one north step.But again there are severe restrictions within this calculations.

Comment: So it's like a 2D random walk, right?

Comment: Something like this, perhaps? https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-solve-for-the-expected-number-of-steps-to-reach-a-certain-point-in-a-random-walk

Comment: Yes matti it's a 2D walk,but the question on Quora is about reaching the destination,but over here it is about the probability of it reaching on nth minute

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting up a recursion. Let expected number of minutes to reach the house be $N$.

Then with $1/4$ probability, man can reach the house in $1$ minute. Otherwise with $3/4$ probability, he ends up in wrong place when he has to come back to the starting point. The man spent $2$ minutes to reach to the initial situation at which point, the expected number of moves is again $N$. Thus we can write
$$N = \frac{1}{4} \times 1 + \frac{3}{4} \times (N+2)$$

which can be solved for $N$.

Answer (score 0):

an analytical solution using geometric series is the following

$$\mathbb{E}[T]=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}(2x+1)\left(  \frac{3}{4}\right)^x=2\cdot\sum_{x=0}^{\infty} x\frac{1}{4}\left(  \frac{3}{4}\right)^x+\frac{1}{4}\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\left(  \frac{3}{4}\right)^x=$$

$$=2\cdot\frac{3}{4}\underbrace{\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}x\frac{1}{4}\left(  \frac{3}{4}\right)^{x-1}}_{=4}+\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{3}{4}}=2\times3+1=7$$

the expression in the "underbrace" is the expectation of a geometric rv with parameter $\frac{1}{4}$, thus it is 4

Comment: Could you please put in detail.